# WebAPI not returning XML even with correct Accepts header

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using ASP.NET WebAPI RC, and hosting an API controller with nothing fancy about it. Everything works fine with JSON, but I'm testing requesting different formats using the Accepts header, and that's where I'm having trouble.

I'm using jQuery to issue an AJAX request, and setting the 'dataType' parameter of the request. This correctly sets the appropriate Accept header as you will see below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: url,
    dataType: "xml",
    data: data || null,
    success: function (data) {
        // omitted
    }
});
```

Here is a save of the fiddler request/response. As you can see the Accept header says application/xml, but WebAPI returned JSON. I have also tried manually setting the Accept header to just "application/xml" (so it doesn't have the text/html stuff as well), but to no avail.

What the heck am I missing? (note: I've *snipped* some confidential info in the data but didn't tweak it otherwise)

```
GET http://localhost/insp**snip**6716 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.60 Safari/537.1
Accept: application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Referer: http://localhost/inspector/api/test?
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: m=34e2:|2c69:t|47ba:t|4e99:t; .INSPECTOR3COOKIE=08BA683091E2A457B1832E9B*snip*F911D9ED97076


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 03 Aug 2012 22:27:42 GMT
Content-Length: 1816

{"Id":2416716,"ProjectId":36,"Url":"http://ins *snip, but obviously this is JSON not XML *
```

I'd like to point out I'm not tweaking any formatters in AppStart or anything, so as far as I understand, the JSON and XML formatters should be enabled by default.

**UPDATE:** I figured it out -- check my own answer below

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I figured it out!

I had this in my AppStart, because I wanted the Xml serializer not the DataContract serializer:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

HOWEVER... apparently there is something about my model that makes the Xml Serializer think it can't serialize it. I am guessing that is causing WebAPI to decide to use the JSON formatter instead.

It's completely non-intuitive that this harmless looking setting could actually affect which formatter is used. Hope the WebAPI people see this :)

Some kind of tool that let you understand the inputs and outputs of content negotiation process so you can debug issues like this would be nice.

Comment: You're right, that's exactly what seems to be happening.

There is a System.Net.Http.Formatting.DefaultContentNegotiator class that has a RunNegotiation method. That method basicly just cycles through all the formatters and checks if they can handle the request. So if the XmlFormatter is for some reason unable to serialize your model to the output stream - it is skipped and the next Formatter is considered - JSON, which happens to be able to serialize your model.

Comment: Setup a TraceWriter and you will see lots of debug information about how the conneg mechanism is working.  See details here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: If you have a cycle in your object graph then XmlSerializer will not be able to handle it.  Also TimeSpans are not supported.

Comment: You can write a test that invokes content negotiation directly on your model, to make sure that it serializes correctly. Also, in the latest Web API source on CodePlex (but not in the RC bits) there is a setting to return 406 in this situation instead of picking another serializer.

Comment: The default conneg behavior, as u can see, is resilient. You can make it picky and send back "406 Not Acceptable" response if the exact type you asked for it not supported: https://gist.github.com/2968263 (I just saw that @HenrikFrystykNielsen already indicated this in his answer).

Comment: When I ran into this problem, my return type had a member of type IEnumerable<>, and changing it to List<> solved this XML issue.

Comment: We should also add to this answer that the WebAPI will fallback to the JsonFormatter if there are any types which the DataContractSerializer or XmlSerializer cannot handle. Both require either the DataContract or Serializable attributes.

Comment: Our solution was to clear all Formatters, then add back an XmlMediaTypeFormatter with UseXmlSerializer = true, then another with UseXmlSerializer = false, then lastly a JsonMediaTypeFormatter. This way if it fails on the first XmlMediaTypeFormatter, you get a second chance before going to JSON. This worked.

Comment: This answer got me where I needed to be. XML content negotiation "suddenly" stopped working. During a refactoring a property was changed from a concrete List<T> to IList<T>. The XmlSerializer obviously could not handle this but the JsonSerializer could. So no matter what content-type/accept was specified, I got back JSON.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue but fixed it by adding default constructors to all the models that I was returning.

The XML serializer creates blank model objects and then populates it via the setters on the properties. If the setters are protected or private then that property will not get serialized either

Comment: I had the same issue.  If the return types don't have parameter-less constructors, web api can't create them and so it falls back to the JSON serializer.

Comment: As correctly said in this answer, types without a parameter-less constructor doesn't work with `XmlSerializer`. Remember the same applies to all `Interfaces/Abstract classes`.

Answer (score 12):

The current answers in this thread already call out a lot of the reasons but just to summarize, the XmlSerializer only supports a limited number of types.

When looking for the "best" formatter, the DefaultContentNegotiator, as correctly described by AASoft, asks each of the formatters whether they can support a particular type. It then matches those formatters against the accept headers in the request.

If it doesn't find any match based on the accept headers then it picks the first that can serialize the type, in this case the JSON formatter. However, you can configure the DefaultContentNegotiator to instead of returning a default format then return a 406 None Accepted status code. This indicates to the client that no matching representation could be found and instead of sending data that the client may not be able to use it generates an error response.

Setting this option is described in the blog "ASP.NET Web API Updates – May 14" [1] under the section "Content Negotiation Improvements".

Hope this helps,

Henrik

[1] http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/05/14/asp-net-web-api-updates-may-14.aspx

Comment: and this resumes in adding `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), new DefaultContentNegotiator(true)); ` to your Application_start.

Answer (score 6):

The answer has already been provided but I thought I'd put my findings so that it might be helpful to anyone coming later.

The culprit was IEnumerable. For example, returning object of Class Album containing IEnumerable and never getting XML return - only JSON.

I used

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

in the Global.asax as well. Which is actually necessary for xml returns. Still I wasn't getting XML back.

Then I Changed the IEnumerable to List and it worked fine. Looks like the XML Formatter in Web API cannot process the IEnumerable in return objects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked for me, I originally thought I might have circular references, but turns out it was just the IEnumerables and I had them all over the place. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

Just as a followup to this.  We had this problem when we had a List of objects in our return model but the object in the list didn't have a parameterless constructor.  Our code looked like this:

```
public class ReturnClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public List<OtherClass> ListOfThings { get; set; }
}

public class OtherClass 
{
    public int OtherValue { get; set; }

    public OtherClass(OtherObject o) 
    {
       this.OtherValue = o.OtherValue;
    }  
}
```

We simply had to add a parameterless constructor for the SubClass object.

```
public class ReturnClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public List<OtherClass> ListOfThings { get; set; }
}

public class OtherClass 
{
    public int OtherValue { get; set; }

    public OtherClass(OtherObject o) 
    {
       this.OtherValue = o.OtherValue;
    }

    public OtherClass()
    {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful using nullable int for any of the properties you  may be serializing.  A nullable int with `config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true` set will cause Web API to return JSON no matter what your accept header says

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add one more reason this might happen, properties with internal get or set. The kind that are generated by VS when you are adding properties to a class by pressing Ctrl-.

like `public string Foo {get; internal set;}`