# Why won't WebAPI return my POCOs as XML?

Tags: serialization, asp.net-web-api, poco

WebAPI is ignoring the Accept: header on the incoming request and appears to be always serializing my POCO objects as JSON. I'm using [WizTools RestClient](https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/downloads/list) to test the API calls, and setting the request HTTP header:

```
GET /api/people/evh123
Accept: application/xml
```

If I modify my controller to return `string[]` or some other native type, I get XML as expected. I've seen several people suggest adding this line to my `Application_Start()` method:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

but in my case this hasn't made any difference.

My API controller:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using Spyglass.Api.Entities;

namespace Spyglass.Api.Controllers {
    public class PeopleController : ApiController {

        public Person Get(string personId) {
            var member = new Person(personId) { FullName = "Eddie van Halen" };
            return (member);
        }
    }
}
```

My route config:

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Spyglass.Api {
    public static class WebApiConfig {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "PeopleApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/people/{personId}/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional, controller = "People"}
                );
        }
    }
}
```

My POCO:

```
namespace Spyglass.Api.Entities {
    public class Person {
        public string PersonId { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public Person(string personId) {
            this.PersonId = personId;
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing some sort of custom serialization config for my POCO? There's none of the circular references or complex types that normally cause XML serializer headaches... any ideas?

Comment: The answer below is probably correct (i.e. the constructor); however, I wanted to point out this answer which covers other potential issues and suggested fixes for others that may come along http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804301/webapi-not-returning-xml-even-with-correct-accepts-header

Answer (score 6):

You need to decorate your object with [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{

    [DataMember]
    public string PersonId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public Person(string id)
    {
        PersonId = id;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, make sure that your POCOs have a default, parameterless constructor.
This is a limitation of DataContractSerializer. You also may use a different serializer.

Comment: Piotr is right about this, you either need to add a default, parameterless constructor or add DataContract/DataMember attributes to get the serializer working.

Comment: I'm jumping in after three years, but this problem just occurred for me. I returned JSON fine, but when I tried to return XML I just got an empty document.  Decorating the model [DataContract] and [DataMember] resolved it.

Answer (score -2):

You can try removing the json formatter from global.asx.cs;

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
```

This will leave only the XML formatter intact.

Comment: If I add that line I get a 406 Not Acceptable response.

Comment: You are seeing a 406 because every formatter during content negotiation is asked if it can write a particular type or not. I this case XmlMediaTypeFormatter's CanWriteType is mentioning false and hence you are seeing this problem. You can check this by doing something like "XmlMediaTypeFormatter frmtr = new XmlMediaTypeFormatter(); bool canWriteType = frmtr.CanWritetype(typeof(Person));"